# Running Scala with pixiedust in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scala, jupyter-notebook, pixiedust

I'm trying to run some scala code in python 3 with jupyter notebook. I have installed pixiedust to make this easier. I have imported it and managed to do that successfully. However, according to the tutorial (https://pixiedust.github.io/pixiedust/scalabridge.html) I should be able to use %scala and then run scala code. This is not working for me and I'm getting an error like this: UsageError: Cell magic `%%scala` not found.

I have tried with both %scala and %%scala, but neither work.

Does anyone know of a different syntax or how this could work?

Thanks!

Comment: are you able to run your scala code without pixiedust?

Comment: @Vishal No, I'm running it in Python 3, so not able to do that. I have also tried the test ipynb files that comes with it, but it is not working after successfully importing the pixiedust. I have also tried running it in python-with-pixiedust_Spark-2.3, but in that notebook I'm not even able to import pixiedust.

Comment: I guess it's not issue of pixiedust. It's the scala issue. I guess a separate kernel (and some installation) is required to run scala.